# XSB Prolog - How can I consult a .p file?

Tags: prolog

Hey guys, this should be quite simple to answer....

Im using XSB Prolog...trying to load a .p prolog database

I have a file xxx.P in directory C:\XSB

So in XSB I type

```
?consult('xxx.p').
```

and i get:

```
cannot find the file or module xxx.p
```

i've tried moving the p file to the same directory as the XSB executable but no luck. Any ideas?

edit:
contents of xxx.p:

```
has_access(tom,123).
has_access(bob,456).
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSB uses the file extension to determine the file type and it only recognizes .P (capital P) and .pl as Prolog files. Name your file with either a .P or .pl extension and consult it that way.

```
| ?- consult('test.p').

no
| ?- consult('test.P').
[Compiling .\test]
[test compiled, cpu time used: 0.0200 seconds]
[test loaded]

yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the fully qualified name of the file like this:

```
 ?consult('C:\\XSB\\xxx.p').
```

If I remember correctly you have to escape the backslashes.

Comment: Returning no means that it found the file so that is progress. Maybe the content of the file needs to be considered now. What does the file contain?

Comment: please see the original post for the contents of the file. thanks